Unable to find a destination matching in fastlane with Github Actions for Swift xcode project
I am getting following error when trying to run unit test cases in my xcode project from github actions using fastlane:
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:983B36D8-0EF5-4C71-BA8B-64D908B7DD14 }
[08:17:33]: Exit status: 70

Following is my fastlane:
desc "Run tests"
  lane :tests do
    scan(scheme: "ProjName Dev")
  end

I tried to run the above project from command line in my local system also but here again I am getting similar error. I am using following like to build it:

xcodebuild build -project "ProjName.xcodeproj" -scheme "ProjName Dev" -configuration "Debug Dev" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15,OS=17.5" test

Error in terminal:
xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 }

I have above simulator installed in macbook.


Unsure you selected an executable in the Scheme Configuration/Run/Info/Executable.

did you try to add the devices as part of the scan parameters? e.g:
scan( scheme: "ProjName Dev" devices: ["iPhone 15 Pro"] )
Note you might need to specifically write the iOS version in the name - "iPhone 15 Pro (iOS 17.5)"
